# A $10^n$ price pattern puzzle

Tags: pattern

This is a chart filled with numbers. The numbers are linked to each other.

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 1 | 0 | 29 | 9 | <sub>1</sub> | 6 | 6 |
| 4 | 77 | 1 | <sub>2</sub> | 2 | 54 | <sub>3</sub> | 2 |
| 60 | <sub>4</sub> | 9 | 9 | <sub>5</sub> | 1 | <sub>6</sub> | 2 |
| 6 | 98 | 97 | <sub>7</sub> | 0 | 0 | 43 | 3 |
| 77 | 8 | <sub>8</sub> | 1 | <sub>9</sub> | 0 | 3 | 8 |
| 8 | 45 | 0 | <sub>10</sub> | 0 | 40 | 0 | 1 |

The question is: find the value of

#### <sub>1</sub><sub>2</sub><sub>3</sub>...<sub>10</sub>

Hint 1:

> 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

Hint 2:

> The numbers are related in rows

Hint 3:

> The numbers can be chained together

Answer (score 5, accepted):

123...10 is:

> 0 coming from the values 95,21,7,205,9,13,0,15,25,98 (or 952172059130152598 if concatenation, or 0 if multiplication)

Because

> As the title and hints allude to, each row reads out 'n' for the equation 10^n=[row # + 1], if one adds a decimal to the front.
>   Reducing this (solving for n), each row is a list of the digits for log(row # + 1).
>   For example, for row # 1: log(1+1) = log(2) = .301029995664, so the missing value for 1 is 95.
>  For row # 2, log(2+1) = log(3) = .47712125472, and so forth.

Comment: Updated concatenation to multiplication